# Filter and display the options of a dropdown, based on the selected value of another dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created two dropdowns using ng-options, in angularJS. The dropdown options get populated by two different array `type_names` and `names`. Both array contain objects as element. Below is the HTML code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedTypeName" ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in type_names">
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in names|filter:{type:'others'}">
</select>

</div>

<p>This example shows how to fill a dropdown list using the ng-options directive.</p>
```

Below is the AngularJS script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type_names = [
        {id: '0', type: 'me', text: 'Master of Computer Engineering'},
        {id: '1', type: 'msc', text: 'Master of Computer Science'},
        {id: '2', type: 'others', text: 'Others'}
    ];

    $scope.names = [
        {id: '', type: 'choose', text: 'Choose a Program'},
        {id: '0', type: 'msc', text: 'Masters - Information Systems Management'},
        {id: '1', type: 'msc', text: 'Masters - Software Engineering'},
        {id: '2', type: 'msc', text: 'Masters - Computer Security'},
        {id: '3', type: 'others', text: 'Bachelors of Computer Science'},
        {id: '4', type: 'others', text: 'Exchange Program'},
        {id: '5', type: 'others', text: 'Study Abroad'},
        {id: '6', type: 'others', text: 'Scientific Summer School'},
        {id: '7', type: 'others', text: 'French Summer School'},
        {id: '8', type: 'me', text: 'ME - Global IT Management'},
        {id: '9', type: 'me', text: 'ME -  Software Development and Multimedia'},
        {id: '10', type: 'me', text: 'ME - Systems, Networks and Security'}
    ];
});
```

As you can see I have used `filter:{type:'others'}` in the second dropdown, so that It'll only display options with `type: others`. Now my objective is to populate the type value(eg. `me`, `others` or `msc`) in `filter:{type:'others'}` automatically, based on the option selected in the first dropdown. For scalability and robustness I do not want to use if/else condition inside the HTML(twig) code.

Note: I am trying to use AngularJS with Symfony2(PHP framework)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can use the type in first dropdown as a filter in second :

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bxr8I3tahgzRluI4TIaW?p=preview

```
<select ng-model="selectedTypeName" 
        ng-options="item.type as item.text for item in type_names">
</select>
<select ng-model="selectedName" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in names|filter:{type:selectedTypeName}">
</select>
```

*What is happening :* Instead of `id:text` pair in first dropdown, `type:text` pair is used. So the value of the first dropdown will be `type` and not `id`;

---

**Solution 2**

And if you want your `id` as the value for the first `select` and not the `type`, then you can use `ngChange` for that :

http://plnkr.co/edit/IjcbVzSSqan8FJ98yRqA?p=preview

```
<select ng-model="selectedTypeId" 
        ng-change="selectedType=(type_names|filter:{id:selectedTypeId})[0].type" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in type_names">
</select>
<select ng-model="selectedName" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in names|filter:{type:selectedType}">
</select>
```

*What is happening :* Whenever a different option is selected in fiorst dropdown, it updates the `selectedType` to the type of the option selected. And that is used for the purpose of filtering the data in the second dropdown.

---

You can default the dropdown values (like you did : `others`), by setting model values in controller :

```
$scope.selectedTypeId = '2';
$scope.selectedType = 'others';
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly :)

Comment: The second answer is again really helpful.

Comment: By the way any ideas how to use AngularJS along with Symfony forms?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution.**

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keyurshah24/m371zeg7/)

This can be done easily using filter. Simple trick part is  `filter: {id: '!' + fruit2.id}`

```
<select ng-model="fruit1.id" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in fruits | filter: {id: '!' + fruit2.id}">
</select>
<select ng-model="fruit2.id" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in fruits | filter: {id: '!' + fruit1.id}">
</select>
```

Inside Contoller.

```
$scope.fruits = [
      {"id":"1","value":"Apple"},
      {"id":"2","value":"Banana"},
      {"id":"3","value":"Cherry"},
      {"id":"4","value":"Fig"},
      {"id":"5","value":"Grapes"}
    ];
        $scope.fruit1.id =  "1";
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for but, with a few tweaks will do th job as well. Thanks